# How to get the size of a Composable during runtime?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout

I have as an example the following Composable:

```
@Composable
fun CustomCanvas(
) {
   Box(
      Modifier
        .aspectRatio(1.33f)
        .fillMaxWidth())
}
```

How do I know the size of this object after composition?

Why I want to know:
I'm trying to resize and place images on a canvas. This requires knowing the size of the canvas. And no, I don't want to hardcode the size of the canvas. How to do this?

Comment: check [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layout#constraints)

Comment: Thanks! Ended up using a BoxWithConstraints within the Box Composable.

Comment: Don't forget to convert into Dp as ```with(localDensity){ coordinates.size.height.toDp() }```

Answer (score 38):

You can use the [**`onGloballyPositioned`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/layout/OnGloballyPositionedModifier) modifier:

```
var size by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero) }

Box(Modifier.onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
    size = coordinates.size
}) {
   //...
}
```

Also the [`Canvas`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/Canvas.html) has a [`DrawScope`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/drawscope/DrawScope) which has the [`size`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/drawscope/DrawScope#size) property.

```
Canvas() {
    val canvasSize = size    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this several ways. `BoxWithConstraints` does not always return correct size because as the name describes it returns `Constraints`. **Max width or height** of `Constraints` doesn't always match **width or height** of your Composable.

Using Modifier.onSizeChanged{size:IntSize} or Modifier.onGloballyPositioned{} with a mutableState causes another recomposition which might cause change in UI on next frame.

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73354911/how-to-get-exact-size-without-recomposition/73357119#73357119) out how to get exact size without recomposition and exact size on every occasion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Modifier.onSizeChanged()` to find the size of a composable at runtime.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Sample() {
    Text(
        "Hello",
        Modifier.onSizeChanged {
            println("Width of Text in dp: ${it.width.toDp}")
            println("Height of Text in dp: ${it.height.toDp}")
        }
    )
}

val Int.toDp get() = (this / Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt()
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for your code.

Comment: Sure. I did just now.

Comment: This function is called toDp, but doesn't produce a DP, please correct this as it's incorrect

Comment: If you set Text’s width or height in dp, the same value will be printed.