# LazyVerticalGrid Adaptive square items

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is there an efficient way to make adaptive grid's item height equal to the width determined in runtime? Basically I want square items.

So far I've tried this:

```
var size by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero) }

Column( // item
...
     .onSizeChanged {
        size = it
     }
    .size(with(LocalDensity.current) {
        size.width.toDp()
    })
)
```

but I'm new to compose and think it might be an expensive operation. Any alternatives?

Comment: Gabriele Mariotti's answer works best i guess. `Modifier.onSizeChanged` requires one more recomposition since size changes from IntZero to actual size, having one more recomposition doesn't have much effect  on performance . However In some cases that change might like a flash or glitch and you have risk of having infinite recompositions, not most of the time but i remember having some infinite recomposition using Modifier.onSizeChanged. You can use BoxWithConstraints or SubcomposeLayout for alternative when size of one Composable effecting another.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/layout/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).onSizeChanged(kotlin.Function1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73354911/how-to-get-exact-size-without-recomposition/73357119#73357119

Answer (score 6):

You can apply the **`aspectRatio`** modifier to the item.
For example:

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
    /* .. */
) {
    items(itemsList) {
        Box(Modifier.aspectRatio(1f)) {

        }
    }
}
```

[image]