# adjust content height with bottom sheet in bottomsheetscaffold

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet, compose-recomposition

I want to change the height of the content dynamically relative to the bottomsheet in the bottomsheetscoffold like this:

[image: bottom sheet collapsed]
[image: bottom sheet expanded]

This is what I have tried so far :
`

```
val bottomSheetState = rememberBottomSheetState(initialValue =BottomSheetValue.Expanded )

val bottomSheetScaffoldState= rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
        bottomSheetState = bottomSheetState)

val heightPixels= LocalContext.current.resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels

BottomSheetScaffold(
modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
sheetPeekHeight = 68.dp,
scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
sheetContent = {
    /*
    sheet content
     */
}) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .fillMaxHeight(((bottomSheetState.offset.value)
                / (heightPixels)).let { if (it == 0f) 1f else it })
    ) {
        /*
        content
         */
    }
}
```

But it's relies on system height in pixel and the box with it's content recompose every time the height of bottom sheet changes

Comment: what about adding a bottom padding to the content container for the same magnitute of the bottom sheet offset?

Answer (score 2):

You can get content height from content using `Modifier.onPlaced/onSizeChanged/onGloballyPositioned` and total height of `BottomSheetScaffold` inside a `BoxWithConstaints` and get height with

### Dynamic content height sample

[image]

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Preview
@Composable
private fun BottomSheetScaffoldHeightSample() {

    val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()

    var sheetPeekHeight by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0.dp)
    }

    val density = LocalDensity.current

    BoxWithConstraints {

        val parentHeight = maxHeight

        SideEffect {
            println("Parent is recomposing...")
        }

        BottomSheetScaffold(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().drawWithContent {
                if (sheetPeekHeight != 0.dp) {
                    drawContent()
                }
            },
            sheetPeekHeight = sheetPeekHeight,
            scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
            drawerShape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
            sheetContent = {

                SideEffect {
                    println("SheetContent. recomposing...")
                }

                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .onPlaced {
                            if (sheetPeekHeight == 0.dp) {
                                sheetPeekHeight = with(density) {
                                    it.size.height.toDp()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(200.dp)
                        .background(Color.Green)
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "sheetContent",
                        color = Color.White,
                        fontSize = 60.sp
                    )
                }
            },
            content = {

                SideEffect {
                    println("Content recomposing...")
                }
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(maxHeight - sheetPeekHeight)
                        .background(Purple400),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Content",
                        color = Color.White,
                        fontSize = 60.sp
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

You can use subComposeLayout approach below here as well you just need to add sheetContent as main content

You can also set sheet height based on content as below

### Dynamic sheet height samples

[image]

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Preview
@Composable
private fun BottomSheetScaffoldHeightSample() {

    val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()

    var sheetPeekHeight by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0.dp)
    }

    val density = LocalDensity.current

    BoxWithConstraints {

        val parentHeight = maxHeight

        BottomSheetScaffold(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().drawWithContent {
                if (sheetPeekHeight != 0.dp) {
                    drawContent()
                }
            },
            sheetPeekHeight = sheetPeekHeight,
            scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
            drawerShape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
            sheetContent = {

                SideEffect {
                    println("SheetContent. recomposing...")
                }

                LazyColumn(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
                ) {
                    items(100) {
                        Text(
                            text = "Row $it",
                            fontSize = 20.sp,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .shadow(2.dp)
                                .background(Color.White)
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .padding(16.dp)
                        )
                    }
                }
            },
            content = {

                SideEffect {
                    println("Content recomposing...")
                }
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                        .onPlaced {
                            if (sheetPeekHeight == 0.dp) {
                                sheetPeekHeight = with(density) {
                                    parentHeight - it.size.height.toDp()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .background(Purple400)
                        .padding(48.dp),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Content",
                        color = Color.White,
                        fontSize = 60.sp
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

However this will schedule recomposition in scope of BoxWithConstaints or any other scope and content since we change height with a MutableState, to not experience jump in content height you can use

`Modifier.drawContent` as in example above.

Other option is to use SubcomposeLayout as in this answer to get exact height without parent recomposition.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73357119/5457853

```
@Composable
fun DimensionSubcomposeLayout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    mainContent: @Composable () -> Unit,
    dependentContent: @Composable (Dp) -> Unit
) {

    SubcomposeLayout(
        modifier = modifier
    ) { constraints: Constraints ->

        // Subcompose(compose only a section) main content and get Placeable
        val mainPlaceables: List<Placeable> = subcompose(SlotsEnum.Main, mainContent)
            .map {
                it.measure(constraints.copy(minWidth = 0, minHeight = 0))
            }

        var maxWidth = 0
        var maxHeight = 0

        mainPlaceables.forEach { placeable: Placeable ->
            maxWidth += placeable.width
            maxHeight = placeable.height
        }

        val dependentPlaceables: List<Placeable> = subcompose(SlotsEnum.Dependent) {
            dependentContent((constraints.maxHeight-maxHeight).toDp())
        }
            .map { measurable: Measurable ->
                measurable.measure(constraints)
            }

        // This are for Modifier.fillMaxSize if you wish to use with other modifiers
        // you need check Constraints bounds and vertical scroll
        layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
            dependentPlaceables.forEach { placeable: Placeable ->
                placeable.placeRelative(0, 0)
            }
        }
    }
}

enum class SlotsEnum { Main, Dependent }
```

And use it as

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Preview
@Composable
private fun BottomSheetScaffoldHeightSample2() {

    val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()

    val content = @Composable {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Purple400)
                .padding(48.dp),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {

            SideEffect {
                println("Content recomposing...")
            }

            Text(
                text = "Content",
                color = Color.White,
                fontSize = 60.sp
            )
        }
    }

    DimensionSubcomposeLayout(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        mainContent = content
    ) { sheetPeekHeight: Dp ->

        SideEffect {
            println("Parent is recomposing...")
        }

        BottomSheetScaffold(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            sheetPeekHeight = sheetPeekHeight,
            scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
            drawerShape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
            sheetContent = {

                SideEffect {
                    println("SheetContent. recomposing...")
                }

                LazyColumn(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
                ) {
                    items(100) {
                        Text(
                            text = "Row $it",
                            fontSize = 20.sp,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .shadow(2.dp)
                                .background(Color.White)
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .padding(16.dp)
                        )
                    }
                }
            },
            content = {
                content()
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it setting `Modifier.fillMaxHeight()` to use the `fraction` value of the scaffold state like below:

```
val bottomSheetState = rememberBottomSheetState(
    initialValue = BottomSheetValue.Expanded
)

val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
    bottomSheetState = bottomSheetState
)

BottomSheetScaffold(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    sheetPeekHeight = 68.dp,
    scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
    sheetContent = {
        /*
        sheet content
         */
    }) {
    val fraction = 1f - bottomSheetScaffoldState.currentFraction
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(bottom = 68.dp)
            .fillMaxHeight(fraction)
    ) {
        /*
        content
         */
    }
}
```

`currentFraction` is a small adjustment on its value because the progress of the drag animation always goes from 0 to 1, no matter if it's from `Collapsed` to `Expanded` or from `Expanded` to `Collapsed` state:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
val BottomSheetScaffoldState.currentFraction: Float
get() {
    val fraction = bottomSheetState.progress.fraction
    val targetValue = bottomSheetState.targetValue
    val currentValue = bottomSheetState.currentValue

    return when {
        currentValue == BottomSheetValue.Collapsed && targetValue == BottomSheetValue.Collapsed -> 0f
        currentValue == BottomSheetValue.Expanded && targetValue == BottomSheetValue.Expanded -> 1f
        currentValue == BottomSheetValue.Collapsed && targetValue == BottomSheetValue.Expanded -> fraction
        else -> 1f - fraction
    }
}
```

The problem of doing like so is that it causes some sort of a flickering when expanding or collapsing the sheet, not ideal.

Comment: .targetValue property is not longer available.