# How to use xml:s android:id in Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, appium-android

How can I use xml:s `android:id` like this:

```
<TextView android:id="@id/randomId">
```

In Jetpack compose? I'm thinking something like this:

```
Text(modifier = Modifier.layoutId("randomId"), text = text)
```

I'm asking because I use Appium which can identify `android:ids` and I would like to do the same for Compose too.

Answer (score 3):

Jetpack Compose is a declarative Ui which you create Ui components with functions with `@Composable` annotation unlike View system where you create instance of View or ViewGroup get it with id you defined to set attributes. In Jetpack Compose you declare attributes of a Composable as parameter of the function.

`Modifier.layoutId` is used when you build custom Composable with a specific layout to calculate dimensions and position of child Composables.

```
/**
 * Retrieves the tag associated to a composable with the [Modifier.layoutId] modifier.
 * For a parent data value to be returned by this property when not using the [Modifier.layoutId]
 * modifier, the parent data value should implement the [LayoutIdParentData] interface.
 *
 * Example usage:
 * @sample androidx.compose.ui.samples.LayoutTagChildrenUsage
 */
val Measurable.layoutId: Any?
    get() = (parentData as? LayoutIdParentData)?.layoutId
```

When you build a custom layout in summary it's as

```
@Composable
private fun MyLayout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {

    Layout(
        modifier = modifier,
        content = content
    ) { measurables: List<Measurable>, constraints: Constraints ->

        val placeables: List<Placeable> = measurables.map { measurable: Measurable ->
            measurable.measure(constraints)
        }

        // Width and height of parent composable depends on requirements
        layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
            placeables.forEach { placeable: Placeable ->
                // place composables based on requirements vertically, horizontally, diagonal, etc.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1- You create a Layout that needs a MeasurePolicy which we set with lambda and returns MeasureResult via `layout(width, height)` function.

2- Constraints are the limits that are set by size modifiers, scroll modifiers or how parent chose to limit size. [In Constraints section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73316247/5457853) i explained which modifier returns which bound. You can measure a measurable only within these bounds.

But you can modify Constraints if you want your Composable to choose different bounds via `constraints.copy()` or `Constraints.fixed()`, `constraints.offset()`. One important thing is max bound  still bound to parent's maxWidth/height in constraints.

Then, you measure your measurables only once, if you try to measure again you get **an exception**.

However, sometimes you need to set dimensions of a Comosable based on another Composable. For instance, an `Image` is 100.dp which is set on runtime and you want `Text` to be adjusted 100.dp and you don't know in which order `Image` an `Text` is added in content.

You either need to use `SubcomposeLayout` which uses subcompose function to remeasure Composables or `Modifier.layoutId` to identify which Composable you measure first as in example below or as in this answer's [Selectively measuring to match one Sibling to Another section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73354911/how-to-get-exact-size-without-recomposition/73357119#73357119)

```
@Composable
private fun MyLayout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {

    Layout(
        modifier = modifier,
        content = content
    ) { measurables: List<Measurable>, constraints: Constraints ->

        val imageMeasurable: Measurable = measurables.find { it.layoutId == "image" }!!
        val textMeasurable: Measurable = measurables.find { it.layoutId == "text" }!!

        val imagePlaceable = imageMeasurable.measure(constraints.copy(minWidth = 0, minHeight = 0))

        // Limit text width to image width by setting min and max width at image width
        val textPlaceable = textMeasurable.measure(
            constraints.copy(
                minWidth = imagePlaceable.width,
                maxWidth = imagePlaceable.width
            )
        )

        val width = imagePlaceable.width
        val imagePlaceableHeight = imagePlaceable.height
        val height = imagePlaceableHeight + textPlaceable.height
        // Width and height of parent composable depends on requirements
        layout(width, height) {
            imagePlaceable.placeRelative(0, 0)
            textPlaceable.placeRelative(0, imagePlaceableHeight)
        }
    }
}
```

Demonstration

```
MyLayout(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .border(1.dp, Color.Cyan)
) {
    Image(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(150.dp)
            .layoutId("image"),
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.landscape1),
        contentDescription = null,
        contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
    )

    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .layoutId("text")
            .border(2.dp, Color.Red),
        text = "Hello world some very long text that will be scaled"
    )
}

MyLayout(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .border(1.dp, Color.Cyan)
) {

    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .layoutId("text")
            .border(2.dp, Color.Red),
        text = "Hello world some very long text that will be scaled"
    )

    Image(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(100.dp)
            .layoutId("image"),
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.landscape1),
        contentDescription = null,
        contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
    )

}
```

Result

[image]

As can be seen in image we used layoutId to get `Image` first then measured `Text` to match its width to `Image`. I don't think this would work with appium unless it has some kind of inspector for `Modifier`

Comment: Good explanation, but it doesn't answer my question of how to use xml:s android:id in Jetpack compose

Comment: This is the closest you can use in Jetpack Compose. As i explained in declerative ui there is no need for id because all of them are functions not instances of object you get after parsing from xml. You need to check out appium documents if it uses an inspector to get Modifier and get id from it. If you check out any Composable project you will see that Modifier.layoutId is almost never used

Comment: Attributes of a Composable is set when add function in your hierarchy not by getting  instance of object. Column(// Properties declared here){} not by getting an istance of this function via tag or id

Comment: @Thracian great explaination to understand the basic knowledge..

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work by setting in your parent layout

`Modifier.semantics { testTagAsResourceId = true}`

Then in your Compose View set the testTag. For example

`Text(text = "Hello, World!", modifier =  modifier.testTag("tvGreeting"))`

This will prompt you to opt into Experimental Compose UI Api. Do that and you are fine.