# How to Get AppBarHeight from AppBar.kt in Compose Android

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-appbarlayout

I want to get this value in `AppBar.kt`

```
private val AppBarHeight = 56.dp
```

I'm using the TopAppBar in a Scaffold and need to know its height, how can I retrieve this value without hard-coding it where I use it? I want to avoid declaring a dimen value for this if possible and measuring the UI element.

Comment: What is the use-case?

Comment: If you don't mind triggering recomposition you can get it via Modifier.onSizeChanged/onGloballyPositioned/onPlaced but triggering recomposition to set another composable might trigger recomposition. And if you don't want to trigger recomposition you can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73354911/how-to-get-exact-size-without-recomposition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a quick look at the code I don't think this is possible. So, the height of the AppBar is set like this: [image]

but the `TopAppBar_Tokens are an internal object:
[image]