# Android compose to anchor a Text to the bottom of a column

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

`Compose androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00`

I am trying to anchor a Text to the bottom of this card. As the image take up more height the date doesn't display at the bottom.

Here is my composable and I have tried many different things to no use.

The empty green box is where I would like to put the date Text.

[image]

```
@Composable
fun NewsItem(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    articleModel: ArticleModel
) {

    var shouldShowProgress by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    Card(
        modifier = modifier,
    ) {
        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .padding(end = 8.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)) {

            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1F)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))) {

                AsyncImage(
                    error = painterResource(id = R.drawable.back_soon),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .aspectRatio(2F / 5F, false)
                        .fillMaxHeight(),
                    onLoading = {
                        shouldShowProgress = true
                    },
                    onSuccess = {
                        shouldShowProgress = false
                    },
                    onError = {
                        shouldShowProgress = false
                    },
                    model = articleModel.urlToImage,
                    contentDescription = null,
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop)

                if (shouldShowProgress) {
                    CircularProgressIndicator(
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
                }
            }

            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .weight(3F)) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                ) {
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        text = articleModel.title,
                        maxLines = 1,
                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                    )

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        text = articleModel.description,
                        maxLines = 5,
                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                    )

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        text = articleModel.author
                    )

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        text = articleModel.sourceName
                    )

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
                }

                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .align(Alignment.BottomEnd),
                    text = articleModel.publishedAt,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.End
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update ======

@F.Msir

I have used your changes and it seems to work. But using the `height(400.dp)` create a effect as there is lots of blank space.
As the content could be larger

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution with comments in order to understand better my approach:

```
@Composable
fun NewsItem(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    articleModel: ArticleModel
) {

    var shouldShowProgress by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    Card(
        //Specify the height if you haven't done earlier from modifier
        modifier = modifier.height(300.dp),
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .padding(end = 8.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1F)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
            ) {

                AsyncImage(
                    error = painterResource(id = R.drawable.back_soon),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .aspectRatio(2F / 5F, true),
                    onLoading = {
                        shouldShowProgress = true
                    },
                    onSuccess = {
                        shouldShowProgress = false
                    },
                    onError = {
                        shouldShowProgress = false
                    },
                    model = articleModel.urlToImage,
                    contentDescription = null,
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                )

                if (shouldShowProgress) {
                    CircularProgressIndicator(
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
                    )
                }
            }

            //You do not need a box only a column, max height is not needed also it is assumed
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(3F)
            ) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    text = articleModel.title,
                    maxLines = 1,
                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                )

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    text = articleModel.description,
                    maxLines = 5,
                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                )

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    text = articleModel.author
                )

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    text = articleModel.sourceName
                )

                //Depending on your case you might add a scroll behaviour so it is better to keep this Spacer
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

                // this fills the entire space of the column and pushes text at the bottom
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    text = articleModel.publishedAt,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.End
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated working example:**

```
Card(
    modifier = modifier,
    colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
        containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant),
    shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium
) {
    Box {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .padding(end = 8.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1F)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
            ) {

                AsyncImage(
                    error = painterResource(id = R.drawable.back_soon),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .aspectRatio(2F / 5F, true),
                    onLoading = {
                        shouldShowProgress = true
                    },
                    onSuccess = {
                        shouldShowProgress = false
                    },
                    onError = {
                        shouldShowProgress = false
                    },
                    model = articleModel.urlToImage,
                    contentDescription = null,
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                )

                if (shouldShowProgress) {
                    CircularProgressIndicator(
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
                    )
                }
            }

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(3F)
                    .fillMaxHeight(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom
            )
            {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .animateContentSize(),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium,
                    text = articleModel.title,
                    maxLines = if (showMoreTitleClicked) Int.MAX_VALUE else 1,
                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                    onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
                        shouldShowMoreTitle =
                            textLayoutResult.hasVisualOverflow || textLayoutResult.lineCount > 1
                    })

                if (shouldShowMoreTitle) {
                    TextButton(
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.End),
                        contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp),
                        onClick = {
                            showMoreTitleClicked = !showMoreTitleClicked
                        }) {
                        Text(
                            text = if (showMoreTitleClicked) "Show less" else "Show more",
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelLarge
                        )
                    }
                }

                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .animateContentSize(
                            animationSpec = spring(
                                dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioLowBouncy,
                                stiffness = Spring.StiffnessLow
                            )
                        ),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge,
                    text = articleModel.description,
                    maxLines = if (showMoreDescriptionClicked) Int.MAX_VALUE else 5,
                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                    onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
                        shouldShowMoreDescription =
                            textLayoutResult.hasVisualOverflow || textLayoutResult.lineCount > 5
                    })

                if (shouldShowMoreDescription) {
                    TextButton(
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.End),
                        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 0.dp),
                        onClick = {
                            showMoreDescriptionClicked = !showMoreDescriptionClicked
                        }) {
                        Text(
                            text = if (showMoreDescriptionClicked) "Show less" else "Show more",
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelLarge
                        )
                    }
                }

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))

                if (articleModel.author.startsWith("https://")) {
                    ClickableText(
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelLarge,
                        text = AnnotatedString(
                            text = articleModel.author,
                            spanStyle = SpanStyle(
                                color = Color.Blue,
                                textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline
                            )
                        ),
                        onClick = {
                            onNewsLinkClicked(articleModel.author)
                        })
                } else {
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth(),
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelLarge,
                        text = articleModel.author
                    )
                }

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))

                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelLarge,
                    text = articleModel.sourceName
                )

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(18.dp))
            }
        }

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomEnd).padding(4.dp),
            text = ZonedDateTime.parse(articleModel.publishedAt).toLocalDate()
                .toString(),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium,
            textAlign = TextAlign.End
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added your code and an left update in the to question. Do you have any other idea. Thanks

Comment: Why you have this code?  `.aspectRatio(2F / 5F, false)` do you think it is needed? I would use the Modifier of AsyncImage as  Modifier.fillMaxSize() only. Also I would use a lower height number than (400.dp) that fits your needs...

Comment: the aspect ratio is need as I want to display in that aspect ratio. However, I don't think that is the issue here.

Comment: Try with .aspectRatio(2F / 5F, `true`) and Maxheight(300.dp) to see if it fits your needs!

Comment: I have updated my answer copy paste my code and see if it works...

Comment: that does work having a fixed height. But I would like to be able to expand the text. Here is the github if you are interested to take a look https://github.com/steve1rm/BusbyNews/tree/master

Comment: Ok check my last working example ;)

Answer (score 2):

Remove `.wrapContentHeight()` from `Row` and use `.height(IntrinsicSize.Max)` instead. This makes your row layout to expand as long as the largest item in it. You have a big image so every other item inside Row that uses `.fillMaxHeight()` would be expanded max to image height

Answer (score 1):

In [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose), if you want to anchor a [`Text` element](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text) to the bottom of a [`Column`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text), you can use the `Modifier.fillMaxHeight()` ([layout modifier](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/basics)) along with [`Arrangement.SpaceBetween`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Arrangement#SpaceBetween()) inside the `Column`. That will make sure the `Text` appears at the bottom.

```java
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight().weight(3F)) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween // this will push the elements to the top and bottom
    ) {
        // The rest of your texts and spacers here

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            text = articleModel.publishedAt,
            textAlign = TextAlign.End
        )
    }
}
```

The `Modifier.fillMaxSize()` to the `Column` fills the entire height of its parent `Box`.
I set `verticalArrangement` to `Arrangement.SpaceBetween` to push the elements to the top and bottom of the `Column`.
The date `Text` should now be placed at the bottom.

The reason for using `Arrangement.SpaceBetween` was to make sure the first set of elements aligns at the top of the `Column`, and the date `Text` anchors at the bottom, with maximum space between them.

You might also consider `Arrangement.Bottom`, but that would mean separating the column into two sections.
The first section would contain the elements that should appear at the top, and the second section would contain the date.
The second section would then be aligned at the bottom using `Arrangement.Bottom`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ali Bardide pointed out you can use `IntrinsicSize.Max` to measure second Box that contains Column.

However, this might or might not have impact on performance because Intrinsic sizes have 2 runs of Placement and Measure scope passes. [Intrinsics do not measure children twice](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements) but do 2 passes of measure and placement.

First one happens with Constraints(0, Constraints.Infinity) where actual height is measured based on width then on next pass both placeables are measured between 0 and the height from first pass.

Adding a Modifier.layout to first or second box it will have pass. In this example it's 4 times because of recomposition of `shouldShowProgress`.

```
 I   News Item MeasureScope Constraints(minWidth = 0, maxWidth = 777, minHeight = 0, maxHeight = Infinity)
 I   News Item MeasureScope Constraints(minWidth = 777, maxWidth = 777, minHeight = 0, maxHeight = 648)
 I  News Item placement Scope
 I   News Item MeasureScope Constraints(minWidth = 0, maxWidth = 777, minHeight = 0, maxHeight = Infinity)
 I   News Item MeasureScope Constraints(minWidth = 777, maxWidth = 777, minHeight = 0, maxHeight = 648)
 I  News Item placement Scope
```

This two passes might or might not have an impact on performance even inside LazyColumn, i will have a benchmark with 2 layouts i created.

```
data class ArticleModel(
    val title: String,
    val description: String,
    val author: String,
    val sourceName: String,
    val publishedAt: String
)

@Composable
fun NewsItem(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    articleModel: ArticleModel
) {

    var shouldShowProgress by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }


    Card(
        modifier = modifier,
    ) {

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(IntrinsicSize.Max)
                .padding(end = 8.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier

                    .weight(1F)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
            ) {

                AsyncImage(
                    error = painterResource(id = R.drawable.avatar_2_raster),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .aspectRatio(2F / 5F, false)
                        .fillMaxHeight(),
                    onLoading = {
                        shouldShowProgress = true
                    },
                    onSuccess = {
                        shouldShowProgress = false
                    },
                    onError = {
                        shouldShowProgress = false
                    },
                    model = "https://i02.appmifile.com/images/2019/06/03/03ab1861-42fe-4137-b7df-2840d9d3a7f5.png",
                    contentDescription = null,
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                )

                if (shouldShowProgress) {
                    CircularProgressIndicator(
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
                    )
                }
            }

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .layout { measurable, constraints ->
                        val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
                        println(" News Item MeasureScope $constraints")
                        layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                            println("News Item placement Scope")
                            placeable.placeRelative(0, 0)
                        }

                    }
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .weight(3F)
            ) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                ) {
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        text = articleModel.title,
                        maxLines = 1,
                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                    )

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        text = articleModel.description,
                        maxLines = 5,
                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                    )

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        text = articleModel.author
                    )

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        text = articleModel.sourceName
                    )

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
                }

                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .align(Alignment.BottomEnd),
                    text = articleModel.publishedAt,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.End
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another option is to create a custom `Layout` that measures content height based on `AsyncImage`, as mentioned here in [Selectively measuring to match one Sibling to Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73354911/how-to-get-exact-size-without-recomposition) section.

Create this `Layout` as

```
@Composable
private fun NewsRow(
    modifier: Modifier,
    spacedBy: Dp = 8.dp,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {

    val measurePolicy = remember {
        object : MeasurePolicy {
            override fun MeasureScope.measure(
                measurables: List<Measurable>,
                constraints: Constraints
            ): MeasureResult {

                require(measurables.size == 2)
                val spacePx = spacedBy.roundToPx()
                val availableWidth = constraints.maxWidth - spacePx
                val imagePlaceable = measurables.first().measure(
                    constraints.copy(
                        minWidth = availableWidth / 4,
                        maxWidth = availableWidth / 4
                    )
                )

                val contentPlaceable = measurables.last().measure(
                    constraints.copy(
                        minWidth = availableWidth * 3 / 4,
                        maxWidth = availableWidth * 3 / 4,
                        minHeight = imagePlaceable.height,
                        maxHeight = imagePlaceable.height
                    )
                )

                val layoutWidth = constraints.maxWidth
                val layoutHeight = imagePlaceable.height

                return layout(layoutWidth, layoutHeight) {
                    imagePlaceable.placeRelative(0, 0)
                    val xPos = imagePlaceable.width + spacePx
                    contentPlaceable.placeRelative(xPos, 0)
                }
            }

        }
    }
    Layout(
        modifier = modifier,
        content = content,
        measurePolicy = measurePolicy
    )

}
```

And use it as

```
@Composable
fun NewsItem2(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    articleModel: ArticleModel
) {

    var shouldShowProgress by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    Card(
        modifier = modifier,
    ) {

        NewsRow(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(end = 8.dp),
            spacedBy = 8.dp
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
            ) {

                AsyncImage(
                    error = painterResource(id = R.drawable.avatar_2_raster),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .aspectRatio(2F / 5F, false)
                        .fillMaxHeight(),
                    onLoading = {
                        shouldShowProgress = true
                    },
                    onSuccess = {
                        shouldShowProgress = false
                    },
                    onError = {
                        shouldShowProgress = false
                    },
                    model = "https://i02.appmifile.com/images/2019/06/03/03ab1861-42fe-4137-b7df-2840d9d3a7f5.png",
                    contentDescription = null,
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                )

                if (shouldShowProgress) {
                    CircularProgressIndicator(
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
                    )
                }
            }

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .layout { measurable, constraints ->
                        val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
                        println(" NewsItem2 $constraints")
                        layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                            println("NewsItem2 placement Scope")
                            placeable.placeRelative(0, 0)
                        }

                    }
            ) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                ) {
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        text = articleModel.title,
                        maxLines = 1,
                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                    )

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        text = articleModel.description,
                        maxLines = 5,
                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                    )

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        text = articleModel.author
                    )

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        text = articleModel.sourceName
                    )

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
                }

                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .align(Alignment.BottomEnd),
                    text = articleModel.publishedAt,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.End
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
 I   NewsItem2 Constraints(minWidth = 777, maxWidth = 777, minHeight = 648, maxHeight = 648)
 I  NewsItem2 placement Scope
 I   NewsItem2 Constraints(minWidth = 777, maxWidth = 777, minHeight = 648, maxHeight = 648)
 I  NewsItem2 placement Scope
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **ConstraintLayout**. Here's an updated version of your **NewsItem** composable:

```
@Composable
fun NewsItem(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    articleModel: ArticleModel
) {
    var shouldShowProgress by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    Card(
        modifier = modifier,
    ) {
        ConstraintLayout(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            val (image, content, date) = createGuidelineFromTop(0.2f).createReferences()

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .constrainAs(image) {
                        top.linkTo(parent.top)
                        start.linkTo(parent.start)
                        end.linkTo(parent.end)
                    }
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
            ) {
                AsyncImage(
                    error = painterResource(id = R.drawable.back_soon),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .aspectRatio(2F / 5F, false)
                        .fillMaxHeight(),
                    onLoading = {
                        shouldShowProgress = true
                    },
                    onSuccess = {
                        shouldShowProgress = false
                    },
                    onError = {
                        shouldShowProgress = false
                    },
                    model = articleModel.urlToImage,
                    contentDescription = null,
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                )

                if (shouldShowProgress) {
                    CircularProgressIndicator(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .align(Alignment.Center)
                    )
                }
            }

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .constrainAs(content) {
                        top.linkTo(image.bottom, 8.dp)
                        start.linkTo(parent.start)
                        end.linkTo(parent.end)
                        bottom.linkTo(date.top)
                    }
            ) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    text = articleModel.title,
                    maxLines = 1,
                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                )

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    text = articleModel.description,
                    maxLines = 5,
                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                )

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    text = articleModel.author
                )

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    text = articleModel.sourceName
                )

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
            }

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .constrainAs(date) {
                        start.linkTo(parent.start)
                        end.linkTo(parent.end)
                        bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                    }
                    .padding(8.dp)
                    .background(Color.Green)
                    .padding(8.dp),
                text = articleModel.publishedAt,
                textAlign = TextAlign.End,
                color = Color.White
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of the constraintLayout are you using. I am getting the error on this line `val (image, content, date) = createGuidelineFromTop(0.2f).createReferences()` I am using this version `implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.1")` the error is unsolved reference: createReferences()

Comment: you need to update your dependency to androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.2 or higher