# I would expect the Image to be recomposed here

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Why is the Image not being recomposed here after the `boxHeight` gets a new value?

Should I trigger recomposition somehow?

*(asking after a long day of trying to get the Image to have the same height as the box which does not have a fixed height - as per design)*

```
@Composable
fun BadgesCardView(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    var boxHeight by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0.dp)
    }

    val density = LocalDensity.current

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .background(color = Colors.blue30, shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 8.dp))
            .noRippleClickable { onClick() }
            .onGloballyPositioned {
                boxHeight = with(density) {
                    it.size.height.toDp()
                }
            },
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .wrapContentWidth(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start
        ) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(
                        horizontal = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.spacing_24),
                        vertical = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.spacing_16)
                    ),
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.badges_mepage_card_header),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 32.sp,
                    fontFamily = Typography.konga,
                    color = Colors.primary30
                )
            )
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(
                        start = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.spacing_24),
                        top = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.spacing_0),
                        end = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.spacing_16),
                        bottom = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.spacing_16)
                    ),
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.badges_mepage_card_body),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                style = Typography.heading5.copy(
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                    color = Colors.neutral80
                )
            )
        }
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(boxHeight)
                .padding(horizontal = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.spacing_16))
                .align(Alignment.CenterEnd),
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.gfx_falling_badges),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think recomposition is an issue here. You can verify with `SideEffect { println("boxHeight: $boxHeight") }`. You should see 0.dp and other size. But even if  worked correctly chaning a Composable size based on other using onGloballyPositioned or onSizeChanged is not a good practice. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/phases#recomp-loop You can set height Image to height of Column using a Layout. you can refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73354911/how-to-get-exact-size-without-recomposition

Comment: Thanks @Thracian for your comment.
I understand the issue of recomposition being inefficient as entities are recomposed using multiple frames, but in this case it will only happen once and being pressed in time, and having solved the problem now (see answer), I'll stick with the recomposition for now. 
Will certainly take the time to learn how to achieve that with Layout and measurables.

Comment: Your problem wasn't recomposition in the first place. As i posted above if you check it with with SideEffect which invokes lambda after successful recomposition you will see that it recomposes. And here one extra composition is not about efficiency, it's about resizing Image one frame later. In some devices these jumps from zero size to assigned size can be visible some times. That's why it's not recommended in official documents also in some cases assigning size to another Composable after recomposition has danger of triggering recomposition.

Comment: And your issue doesn't look like it has anything to do recomposition. You can also verify this by assigning Modifier.border to image to observe its size change visually with ContentScale.Fit as well. Recomposition happens in a scope a State is read when that value changes. ContentScale does not effect recomposition

Comment: But contentScale effects how aspect ratio is set because you never assign a width to image and based on internal calculation its assigned.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It's my first real go at Compose so there is much to learn. SideEffect printed 3 times. Twice with 0.0 and once with the new value. That means that the whole view/composable was created 3 times, right?
I'll definitely give it a go using a Layout instead 

Comment: I understand that ContentScale shouldn't have effect on recomposition. That's why I think it's interesting that I do get the desired effect with `ContentScale.FillHeight` (which also keeps the ratio as you mentioned) but not with `ContentScale.Fit` 
I'll try to add a border to see if I can see a visual difference.

Comment: Composition and 2 recompositions followed after that should have no effect on performance. If you don't see a jump in next frame image is resized you can use Modifier.onGlobabllyPositioned. I just commented there might be unexpected side effects in some situations. And, yes, if you see `SideEfffect` printed 3 times it means it's called in composition then in twice in recomposition. It's very useful Composable to track recompositions.

Comment: ContentScale is used to determine drawing area and Composable size if you didn't assign a limiting size Modifier using Bitmap dimensions and Constraints or size available to Image Composable. It's just a ratio formula to draw your image correctly and in desired or closest to desired ration in `Image`.

Comment: Using Layout without mastering can be difficult for a beginner, you need to learn how Constraints or size Modifiers effect first, i suggest you to use your current function and keep in mind that things i mentioned above.

Comment: Why it's not drawn is only depends on your size of your image and dimensions available in your device for `Image` composable. I tested code your with `ContentScale.Fit` and no issue with my images. That's what i meant

Comment: And last but not least, Modifier.border is insanely helpful when building custom layouts or to check if your Composable actually occupy size or not when building screens. I use it very often. I also use it and Modifier.background with some random color to see recomposition counts visually either as in these answers. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71016788/5457853, https://stackoverflow.com/a/74700668/5457853

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:**
*Not a recomposition issue probably. See discussion above* ☝️

I changed the `contentScale = ContentScale.Fit` to `contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight` and the image recomposed to the height of `boxHeight` which is the height of the `Box`.

```
...
Image(
    modifier = Modifier
        .height(boxHeight)
        .padding(horizontal = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.spacing_16))
        .align(Alignment.CenterEnd),
    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.gfx_falling_badges),
    contentDescription = null,
    contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight // <--
)
...
```