# How to know the relative position of composable when giving it a custom layout?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to create a custom Compose layout where elements (primarily inside a `Column`) have their maximum width constrained depending on their position inside the parent.

I've come up with the following `Modifier` that does it:

```
fun Modifier.widthDependingOnTop() = composed {
    var parentY by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(Float.NaN) }
    onPlaced {
        parentY = it.positionInParent().y
    }.layout { measurable, constraints ->
        val placeable = measurable.measure(
            if (parentY <= 200f) {
                constraints.copy(maxWidth = 100)
            } else {
                constraints
            }
        )
        layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
            placeable.placeRelative(x = 0, y = 0)
        }
    }
}
```

I used it the following way:

```
Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
    repeat(5) {
        Row(Modifier.widthDependingOnTop().background(Color.Red)) {
            Text("lorem ipsum")
        }
    }
}
```

And it produced the expected result:

[image]

However, this isn't ideal because the content flashes briefly when it's displayed - I understand this is because I'm waiting for `onPlaced` to know the coordinates inside the parent, after which I modify the width (potentially).

I could avoid this if there's a way inside `layout{}` to know the position where the composable will appear inside the parent, however I wasn't able to find anything akin to that. Is there a way to do this? Perhaps a modifier should be applied to the parent `Column` and not the children?

Answer (score 1):

You can move this logic inside `Layout` if you don't want your Composable to be recomposed when size changes as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73357119/5457853).

However if you wish to keep using Modifier you can delay drawing one or few frames by using `Modiifer.drawWithContent{drawContent()}` with a condition.

To wait one frame you can call `awaitFrame` inside corotineScope but if you still see flash you can set some fixed number to delay draw phase as

```
fun Modifier.widthDependingOnTop() = composed {
    var parentY by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(Float.NaN) }

    var draw by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(parentY) {
        if (parentY.isNaN().not()) {
//            delay(50)
            awaitFrame()
            draw = true
        }
    }
    onPlaced {
        parentY = it.positionInParent().y
    }
        .drawWithContent {
            if (draw) {
                drawContent()
            }
        }
        .layout { measurable, constraints ->
            val placeable = measurable.measure(
                if (parentY <= 200f) {
                    constraints.copy(maxWidth = 100)
                } else {
                    constraints
                }
            )
            layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                placeable.placeRelative(x = 0, y = 0)
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/bestpractices#defer-reads