# Get Size of child elements and update size of layout in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a layout, inside it I have an image set as background. The height of that layout increases as the content inside that layout increases.

I wanted to know if there is any way to calculate the size of the layout and set the image height at runtime. Currently the image size is set to matchParentSize.

```
ConstraintLayout(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .verticalScroll(scrollState)
        .weight(1f)
) {

    val (qrArea, details) = createRefs()

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(red)
            .constrainAs(qrArea) {
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
            }
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.mes),
            contentDescription = "null",
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(columnHeight.value.dp),
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
        )

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(brush = destinationImageGradient)
                .matchParentSize()
        )

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.onGloballyPositioned {
                columnHeight.value = it.size.height
            }
        ) {
            AppBar(
                startIcon = R.drawable.ic_back,
                backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                startIconClick = {}
            )

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(start = 62.dp, top = 0.dp, end = 62.dp, bottom = 66.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.qr),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier.size(qrCodeImageSize),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                )

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = ("A Random Text").uppercase(),
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = ("Random Text Two Sub").uppercase(),
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to solve it using onGloballyPostined method. But the image then was taking the entire screen height rather than the size of the content inside that box which has image and the text.

```
            .onGloballyPositioned { layoutCoordinates ->
                columnHeight.value = layoutCoordinates.size.height
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Layout` for measuring child Composables and setting parent height or `SubcomposeLayout` for getting height and passing it to a child on its composition phase as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73357119/5457853), also  height is not in next obtained on frame or no recomposition is triggered to get it.

But the reason you set incorrect height is you don't do conversion from pixel to dp after getting height in `Modifier.onGloballyPositioned`.

```
val density = LocalDensity.current 

.onGloballyPositioned { layoutCoordinates: LayoutCoordinates ->
    with(density) {
        columnHeight.value = layoutCoordinates.size.height.toDp()
    }
}
```

How it should be done and change type of columnHeight from int to dp if you wish to set some Modifier height.

Let's say your device has 2.0f density, and you get 200px height from layoutCoordinates simply by setting `columnHeight.value.dp` you set Column height to 200.dp while it should be 200px/2.0f = 100.dp which `toDp()` does.

```
/**
 * Convert an [Int] pixel value to [Dp].
 */
@Stable
fun Int.toDp(): Dp = (this / density).dp
```