# How to properly measure views in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am making a simple switch where the icon moves from left to right and text from right to left.

before i layout items i need to know in advance few things:

1. maximum width of view to evaluate  how far the icon can move (currently i use onGloballyPositioned)
2. size of the longest text to fix size for wrap content mode (currently i use invisible textview with the longest text as  a placeholder)

both my workarounds are definitly far away from good practice but i cannot understand how to use BoxWithConstraints.

```
val iconSize = 32.dp

@Composable
fun MemoTargetSwitch(
    modifier: Modifier,
    isChecked: Boolean,
    onValueChanged: (Boolean) -> Unit
) {
    val animationPath = remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    val padding = 6.dp

    // total view size

    val dencity = LocalDensity.current
    // we need pixels for animation,  so need convert dp to px
    val iconSizePx = dencity.run { (iconSize).toPx() }
    val paddingPx = dencity.run { padding.toPx() }


    var isCheckedLocal by remember { mutableStateOf(isChecked) }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    // if we update isCheck value from outside after  view was created, than view will ignore new value.
    // for update  to take effect we  need to updat eit in  dispossable effect
    DisposableEffect(isChecked) {
        if (isCheckedLocal != isChecked) {
            scope.launch {
                isCheckedLocal = isChecked
            }
        }
        onDispose { }
    }
    // variable progress  from 0 to 1
    val animatePosition by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (isCheckedLocal) 1f else 0f,
        animationSpec = tween(300, easing = EaseInCirc)
    )
    // Change ting color
    val text = if (isCheckedLocal) "For others" else "For me"
    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = modifier
            .height(32.dp)
            .border(
                1.dp,
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)
            )
            .onGloballyPositioned { coordintates ->
                animationPath.intValue =
                    coordintates.size.width - paddingPx.toInt() * 2 - iconSizePx.toInt()

            }
            .clickable(
                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                indication = null
            ) {
                isCheckedLocal = !isCheckedLocal
                onValueChanged(isCheckedLocal)
            }
    ) {
        Row(
            Modifier
                .padding(start = padding, end = padding)
                .align(Alignment.CenterStart),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            // we put text into animated content to animate change.
            // in transition spec we should first set enter animation, than couple it with exit animation
            SwitchIcon(
                isChecked = isCheckedLocal, modifier = Modifier.graphicsLayer(
                    translationX = animatePosition * animationPath.value,
                    rotationX = animatePosition * 360
                )
            )
            SwitchText(value = text, padding = padding, modifier = Modifier
                .graphicsLayer { translationX = -animatePosition * iconSizePx }
            )


            // wrapper for icon.

        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun SwitchText(value: String, padding: Dp, modifier: Modifier) {
    val textForMe = "For me"
    val textForOthers = "For others"
    val longestText = if (textForMe.length > textForOthers.length) {
        textForMe
    } else {
        textForOthers
    }
    Box() {
        Text(
            text = longestText,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(bottom = 2.dp, start = padding)
                .alpha(0f), maxLines = 1, overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
        )
        AnimatedContent(
            modifier = modifier,
            targetState = value,
            transitionSpec = { fadeIn() togetherWith fadeOut() },
            label = "switch text"
        ) { animatedText ->
            Text(
                text = animatedText,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 2.dp, start = padding),
                maxLines = 1,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
            )
        }

    }

}

@Composable
private fun SwitchIcon(isChecked: Boolean, modifier: Modifier) {
    val animatedColor by animateColorAsState(targetValue = if (isChecked) Color.Red else Color.Green)
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .size(iconSize)
            .zIndex(1f),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.StickyNote2,
            contentDescription = "note switch",
            tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseSurface
        )
        // just outline for some interaction
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Outlined.StickyNote2,
            contentDescription = "note switch",
            tint = animatedColor,
            modifier = Modifier.alpha(0.3f)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don' assign `Modifier.width` of `Modifier.fillMaxWidth` modifier BoxWithConstraints returns parent `maxWidth` not width of itself or content. You can use SubcomposeLayout to defer composition which means you can pass any dimension before triggerring recomposition. You can refer this answer for detailed explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73354911/how-to-get-exact-size-without-recomposition/73357119#73357119

Comment: BoxWithConstraints is also SubcomposeLayout, it gets `Constraints` based on its modifier and passes to Content calling its composition. By writing your own you can pass exact measurment instead of Constaints which is range based on modifiers assigned. You can refer answer below for how size is calculated and how size Modifiers, Constraints work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65779226/android-jetpack-compose-width-height-size-modifier-vs-requiredwidth-requir/73316247#73316247